# Using only the necessary parts of the fact just to prove the point

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for 'using the facts for one's own favorable use' or disregarding other points of fact just to prove the point?

Answer (score 1):

**cherry-pick (v.), cherry-picking (n.)**

> Intransitive verb
>
> To select the best or most desirable
>
> Transitive verb
>
> To select as being the best or most desirable [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cherry-pick)

> Transitive verb
>
> If someone cherry-picks people or things, they choose the best ones
> from a group of them, often in a way that other people consider
> unfair. [Collins](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cherry-pick)
>
> *The team is in debt while others are lining up to cherry-pick their best players.*

> **Cherry picking**, suppressing evidence, **or the fallacy of incomplete
> evidence** is the act of pointing to individual cases or data that seem
> to confirm a particular position while ignoring a significant portion
> of related and similar cases or data that may contradict that
> position. **Cherry picking** may be committed intentionally or
> unintentionally. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking)

---

> But clearly  they **cherry-pick** and distort the facts for the
> purpose of presenting a very different understanding than one would
> get from a more accurate, balanced reporting.
>
> In my view, **cherry-picking** information and grossly distorting facts are not examples of mistakes, inaccuracies, or differing perspectives. They're fake news. They're intended to mislead. [Eric Sentel; *Become
> your Own Fact-Checker*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Become_Your_Own_Fact_Checker/NAf1DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cherry%20pick%20the%20facts&pg=PA54&printsec=frontcover)

> **Cherry-picking** is a common practice. Various movements and industries
> have practiced it, taking care to exclude studies that don’t go their
> way. They only select studies that support their position.  [Valérie Levée; "**Cherry-picking**:
> choosing facts that confirm what you want!"](https://www.covid-desinfo.ca/en/infographics/cherry-picking-choosing-facts-that-confirm-what-you-want)

> **Classic cherry picking**: misleading viewers by producing and
> displaying graphs based on carefully selected data specifically aimed
> to apparently contradict global warming. Classic examples include
> **cherry picking** of places or regions where show cooling despite a general global warming trend and **cherry picking** of period of time
> with limited warming (or even cooling)... [B. Schneider and T. Nocke;
> *Image Politics of Climate Change*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Image_Politics_of_Climate_Change/DcLWBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cherry-picking&pg=PA166&printsec=frontcover)